# Как текст превращался в смайл на PHP?

Tags: php

кто нибудь сможет написать функцию для того что бы текст превращался в смайл? Что бы он считывал весь файл _define.ini из папки со смайлами в QIP и что бы проходил поиск и замена текста. массив с именами смайлов создавать не надо, пусть замена будет если строка где нашелся смайл на пример 5, то что бы было `<img src='smiles/5.gif'>`. Хочется сделать что бы все варианты смайлов поддерживались (( Таков мой план:

```
папка smiles. текст выглядит так: :), =), :-) и т.д., новые на следующей строке. мой способ искать в какой строке лежит смайл в файле _define.ini и менять, на пример, =) на <img src='smiles/$номер_строки.gif'>


$m_myrow_message = "=)";
function smiles($m_myrow_message) {
    if(!file_exists($file="img/smiles/_define.ini"))
    return false;
    $info_smiles = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach($info_smiles as $num_str=>$cur_str)
    {
        $arr_str=explode(",", $cur_str);
        foreach($arr_str as $key=>$value)
        $m_myrow_message=str_replace($value, "<img src='img/smiles/".$num_str.".gif' alt=''/>", $m_myrow_message);
    }
    return $m_myrow_message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function smiles($m_myrow_message)
{
    if(!file_exists($file = "img/smiles/_define.ini")) { return FALSE; }
    $smiles = file_get_contents($file);
    // разделитель может быть не PHP_EOL a \n или \r\n...
    foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $smiles) as $num => $smile)
    {
        $smile_array = explode(",", $smile);
        foreach($smile_array as $value)
        {
            $m_myrow_message = str_replace($value, "<img src='img/smiles/".$num.".gif' alt=''/>", $m_myrow_message);
        }
    }
    return $m_myrow_message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, чтобы вас сейчас не затроллили, вы должны четко расписать

- что за папка, из которой стоит извлекать смайлы
- как выглядит текст, в котором фрагменты надо заменить на графические изображения
- какие способы могли бы предложить вы(пусть просто словами)
- какие, по вашему, функции из PHP вам могут помочь в этом (подсказка: ищите тут:http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.dir.php)

Кстати, нелишним было бы скинуть пару нерабочих функций, а если точнее - конкретно места, на которые ругается PHP.

А еще вам понадобится str_replace(). Но это уже высший пилотаж:

```
$message = str_replace(array(':(',':)'),array('<img src="smile_sad.jpg" />','<img src="smile_happy.jpg" />'),$message);
```

Comment: через str_raplace понадобится много места в PHP файле. папка smiles. текст выглядит так: :), =), :-) и т.д., новые на следующей строке. мой способ искать в какой строке лежит смайл в файле _define.ini и менять, на пример, =) на <img src='smiles/$номер_строки.gif'>, вот и всё )

Comment: вы свой способ не изложили. А зря. У вас все еще есть шанс исправиться. Поправьте ваш вопрос, дополнив его своим примером. Там же уточните именно те детали, которые вас интересуют.

Comment: Добавил, можешь посмотреть.